# Finding possible permutations for range of values with changing parameters

Tags: javascript, c#, algorithm, if-statement, permutation

Possible ranges with assigned actions:

```
if(val == middle) Run()
2. if(val > middle && val < top1) Run()
3. if(val >= top1 && val < top2) PickWeapon()
4. if(val >= top2) Jump()
5. if(val < middle && val > bottom1) Run()
6. if(val <= bottom1 && val > bottom2) DropWeapon()
7. if(val <= bottom2) Crawl()
```

Problem description:

I need to find all possible permutations in case if any of the following params: **top2, top1, middle, bottom1, bottom2** becomes null - then range and action is changing  i.e

```
function Permutations(top2, top1, middle, bottom1, bottom2, val){
    if(val)
    {
        //all defined
        if(top2 && top1 && middle && bottom1 && bottom2)
        {
            if(val == middle)
            {
                Run();
            } 
            else if(val > middle && val < top1)
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(val >= top1 && val < top2)
            {
                PickWeapon();
            }
            else if(val >= top2)
            {
                Jump();
            }
            else if(val < middle && val > bottom1)
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(val <= bottom1 && val > bottom2)
            {
                DropWeapon()
            }
            else if(val <= bottom2)
            {
                Crawl();
            }

        }
        //top1 missing
        if(top2 && !top1 && middle && bottom1 && bottom2)
        {
            if(val == middle)
            {
                Run();
            } 
            else if(val > middle && val < top2) //!!! new range
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(val >= middle && val < top2) //!!! new range
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(val >= top2)
            {
                Jump();
            }
            else if(val < middle && val > bottom1)
            {
                Walk();
            }
            else if(val <= bottom1 && val > bottom2)
            {
                DropWeapon()
            }
            else if(val <= bottom2)
            {
                Crawl();
            }
        }
        //top1 and bottom1 missing
        if(top2 && !top1 && middle && !bottom1 && bottom2)
        {
            if(val == middle)
            {
                Run();
            } 
            else if(val > middle && val < top2) //!!! new range
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(val >= middle && val < top2)  //!!! new range
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(val >= top2)
            {
                Jump();
            }
            else if(val < middle && val > bottom2)  //!!! new range
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(val <= middle && val > bottom2)  //!!! new range
            {
                Run();
            }
            else if(val <= bottom2)
            {
                Crawl();
            }
        }
        if(!top2 && top1 && middle && bottom1 && !bottom2)
        if(top2 && top1 && !middle && bottom1 && bottom2)
        if(top2 && top1 && !middle && bottom1 && !bottom2)
        ...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write an algorithm for this problem so I can avoid writing if statements from hand ?? Any suggestions??

Thanks

Comment: do you really need all permutations? maybe you could take a picture with the position of val and visualize before and make then the comparisons. btw, if a single function is taken, you could return early and omit `else` statements.

Comment: Any reason for the `c#` tag? Also there are several conditions for the `Run()` result, maybe you could use `||` so you have only one `if` for that

Comment: Also, `top1` and `!top1` will not result in what you think if `top1` equals `0` (which is different from `null`)

Comment: c# and JS tags are here because I can implement solution in either of these. I treat this code as a sudo code, I will take care of 0 case, thanks for pointing.

Comment: Title says "permutations", body says "combinations". Both should say "combinations" I assume...

Comment: @MatthewWatson Fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at those parts in "*top1 and bottom1 are missing*":

```
if(val == middle)
{
    Run();
} 
...
else if(val > middle && val < top2) //!!! new range
{
    Run();
}
else if(val >= middle && val < top2)  //!!! new range
{
    Run();
}
...
else if(val < middle && val > bottom2)  //!!! new range
{
    Run();
}
else if(val <= middle && val > bottom2)  //!!! new range
{
    Run();
}
```

Nothing that bothers you?

I mean, if `val >= middle && val < top2` then `val` would already be `== middle` so you will never even reach this point.
Same goes for `val <= middle && val > bottom2`.

Therefore, you could just as well have written:

```
if(val == middle ||                 // either val is equal to middle
   (val > middle && val < top2) ||  // or it is more than middle and less than top2
   (val < middle && val > bottom2)) // or it is less than middle and more than bottom2
{
    Run();
}
```

Anyway, it seems pretty clear to me that your assigned actions look like this:

```
-----bottom2----bottom1----middle ---- top1 ---- top2 ------
|       |          |                    |          |       |
| Crawl |DropWeapon|         Run        |PickWeapon| Jump  |
|_______|__________|____________________|__________|_______|

if(val <= bottom2)
    Crawl();
else if(val <= bottom1)
    DropWeapon();
else if(val < top1)
    Run();
else if(val < top2)
    PickWeapon();
else
    Jump();
```

If I understand well, then with `top1` missing, it would give:

```
-----bottom2----bottom1----middle ---- top2 -----
|       |          |                    |       |
| Crawl |DropWeapon|         Run        | Jump  |
|_______|__________|____________________|_______|

if(val <= bottom2)
    Crawl();
else if(val <= bottom1)
    DropWeapon();
else if(val < top2) // change to top2
    Run();
//else if(val < top2)
//    PickWeapon();
else
    Jump();
```

The previous two situations can be simplified to:

```js
function Permut(bottom2, bottom1, middle, top1, top2, val) {
    if(val <= bottom2)
        console.log('Crawl();')
    else if(val <= bottom1)
        console.log('DropWeapon();')
    else if(top1 !== null && val < top1 ||
            top1 === null && val < top2)
        console.log('Run();')
    else if(val < top2)
        console.log('PickWeapon();')
    else
        console.log('Jump();')
}

Permut(5, 10, 15, 20,   25, 21)
Permut(5, 10, 15, null, 25, 21)
```

If we want to handle both top1 and top2 being nullable, we can write:

```js
function Permut(bottom2, bottom1, middle, top1, top2, val) {
    if(val <= bottom2)
        console.log('Crawl();')
    else if(val <= bottom1)
        console.log('DropWeapon();')
    // here we check top1 as upper bound if it is not null
    // top2 as upper bound if top1 is null
    // no upper bound if both are null
    else if(top1 !== null && val < top1 || 
            top1 === null && (top2 === null || val < top2))
        console.log('Run();')
    // upper bound is top2 if it is not null
    // else there is no upper bound
    else if(top2 === null || val < top2)
        console.log('PickWeapon();')
    else
        console.log('Jump();')
}

Permut(5, 10, 15, 20,   25, 21)
// top1 null means we can't PickWeapon
Permut(5, 10, 15, null, 25, 21)
Permut(5, 10, 15, null, 25, 27)
// top2 null means we can't Jump
Permut(5, 10, 15, 20, null, 27)
// both top1 and top2 null means we can neither PickWeapon nor Jump
Permut(5, 10, 15, null, null, 27)
```

Then all you have to do is handle:

```
// bottom1 null means we can't DropWeapon
// bottom2 null means we can't Crawl
```

---

For code coverage, the following snippet will give you all the 32 combinations:

```js
var bo2="B2", bo1="B1", mid="MI", to1="T1", to2="T2";
var b2, b1, mi, t1, t2;

var empty = "__";

for(var i=0;i<2;i++) {
    b2 = i==0?bo2:empty;
    for(var j=0;j<2;j++) {
        b1 = j==0?bo1:empty ;
        for(var k=0;k<2;k++) {
            mi = k==0?mid:empty ;
            for(var l=0;l<2;l++) {
                t1 = l==0?to1:empty;
                for(var m=0;m<2;m++) {
                    t2 = m==0?to2:empty;
                    
                    console.log(b2+"."+b1+"."+mi+"."+t1+"."+t2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You might then be able to replace the first line with actual values, like `2,4,6,8,10`, and replace `"__"` with `null` so you get all your possible inputs except `val`.
Then, instead of calling `console.log(...)` you could add a loop with `val` from `1` to `11` so you get every cases (including edge cases).
This means you get `32*11 = 352` iterations for complete coverage.

This is a [C# example](http://tpcg.io/B5wYUN).

Comment: Assigned actions looks exactly as you showed. The null values might be there, I'm dealing with the legacy code, my call is only to use null or 0. Need to take a moment to think through the rest of your answer...

Comment: thanks for the explanation and snippets I will follow your approach. Also any idea if I can  programmatically confirm coverage of all the cases?

Comment: Actually, running my C# example, it seems to cover each case pretty well, as long as `b2 < b1 < mi < t1 < t2` (remove variable when null)

Comment: What's interesting is that `middle` isn't really needed, so you could shorten test cases, with `[2,4,6,8]` for `[b2,b1,t1,t2]` and take `val` from `1` to `9` which would shorten the number of iterations to `2^4 * 9 = 16*9 = 144`

Comment: Appriciate your help! @Rafalon

Comment: I used your c# example and added as I thought the rest of the missing cases: http://tpcg.io/DqNaIG, this makes me dizzy... , would you recommend a way of validating it, I kinda don't trust myself, with that many conditions. @Rafalon

Comment: @CodeHooligan your code makes me believe you didn't understand the point of my answer, as you kept your initial schema... And I thought that was exactly what you wanted to avoid

Comment: @CodeHooligan What you need is to think about "*when do we want the character to `Crawl`?*" Answer: "*when `bottom2` is not null and `val` is less than or equal to `bottom2`*" then you write `if(bottom2 !== null && val <= bottom2){Crawl();}`. I let you think about "*when do we want the character to `DropWeapon`?*"

Comment: now I realize my nonsense, thanks for the patience. You basically gave me all the answers and I still messed up. So as you pointed previously the only change is needed to Run case: if((top1 != null && val < top1 || 
           top1 == null && (top2 == null || val < top2)) || (bottom1 != null && val > bottom1 || bottom1 == null && (bottom2 == null || val > bottom2)))
            return "Run();";